# jQuery setting variables from url string

Tags: jquery

I have a URL string like http://www.example.com/?chicken?toast

And I want to be able to store the values after each of the ? characters.

I have it working getting the last ?value - but cant seem to store the first...

Code that works to get the last ?value is:

```
window.lastValue = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('?') + 1);
```

How can I store the first also?

So firstValue = chicken and lastValue = toast

UPDATE - How can I also store a totalVal by flattening the array? So, if the array was ["chicken", "toast"] I need this flattened into a string with a "." before each item in the array - so if the array was ["chicken", "toast"] it would become ".chicken.toast" - if the array was ["chicken"] it would become ".chicken" // thanks

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an array of the values you want:

```
var r = window.location.href.split("?");
r.shift();
console.log(r);
```

If there are always exactly two values, you can use this to extract them:

```
var val1 = r.shift();
var val2 = r.shift();
```

Here's a version which gives the `.chicken` result:

```
var r = window.location.href.split("?");
r[0]='';
var totalval = r.join('.');
```

Comment: OK thanks - then will need to flatten array into 2 vars yeh?

Comment: You can extract the values of the array how you like. I've edited to show one way.

Comment: Last question if that's OK... Can I flatten array into 1 variable, with the values seperated with "." - so it would be: var totalval = ".chicken.toast" if there were 2 paramaters in the string, and var totalval = ".chicken" if just one?

Comment: I've added a further edit to give the `.chicken.toast` output

Comment: Thanks Chris - I assume I can run the scripts so I can extract both a joined list of the array results - e.g. ".chicken.toast" as well as single variables - e.g. "chicken" and "toast"?

Comment: Yes. Put all the lines with `shift` in them after the definition of `totalval`

Comment: Sweet! Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
// obviously, in production you should use document.location.href:
var url = "http://www.example.com/?chicken?toast",

// take a substring of the url variable, starting at the index of
// the (first) '?' character and running to the end of the string,
// giving "?chicken?toast", we then split that resultant string
// on the '?' characters, and filter the resulting array using
// filter(Boolean), which retains only the true/truthy array-elements:
    values = url.substring(url.indexOf('?')).split('?').filter(Boolean);
console.log(values);
```

```js
var url = "http://www.example.com/?chicken?toast",
    values = url.substring(url.indexOf('?')).split('?').filter(Boolean);
console.log(values);
```

You could, instead, use `document.location.search` to retrieve the substring from the first `'?'` onwards (if using `document.location.href`).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: Thanks - that drops them into an array yeh - so will then need to parse them from the array into 2 variables yeh?

Comment: Or simply address them as `values[0]`, `values[1]`: they're already in an Array, you can access them using array[index] notation.

Comment: Thanks. All understood.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    // Do something with the name sParameterName[0]
    // Do something with the value sParameterName[1]
    }
```

This reference may be of some use to you:
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html